# Not able to get my Huawei E303f USB modem working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, usb-modem, huawei

I have been searching for a way to get my USB modem working. I am on ubuntu 14.04. I know that ubuntu takes these modems as a mass storage device at first. Therefore, I used `modprobe` and `ubs-modeswitch` to switch the modes but no avail. I installed the driver too, and it says successfully installed. At first, Ubuntu treated it as a USB modem but after a reboot it faded away.

The `lsusb` output :

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:685e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (USB Debugging mode)
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e032 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
    Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The **relevant** `dmesg` output :

```
[  414.605997] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  414.622875] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1446
[  414.622879] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  414.622882] usb 3-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  414.622884] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  414.622885] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
[  414.666998] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  414.667059] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[  415.677870] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  415.679161] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  415.679664] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[  415.679780] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  415.679845] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5
[  415.680002] sd 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[  415.683788] sd 8:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  416.064857] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[  416.067547] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[  423.196151] systemd-hostnamed[4145]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  442.702179] ideapad_laptop: Unknown event: 1
[  449.626373] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  449.626385] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  449.626392] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  449.630494] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[  449.630509] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
```

Whenever I try to create a new mobile broadband connection, it does not show up the Huawei modem option in the Network Manager tab.